# Why do we need to change files i_generation number?

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems

Why we have an interface to change the i_generation number of file using chattr -v when FS already increments it when allocating a new inode from unused list?

Is there any other use of it apart from its usage in NFS(detecting stale file handles on inode reused after file deletion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the gen number invalidates any open file handles right? If so, all future reads of the file will fail. So, if I were to guess, I would say this is one way to invalidate all open file handles, kind of in a lazy fashion, without the server maintaining any state about who has open file handles.

Comment: Sure Isk. But this is in case of NFS....but what is its use in physical FS, and if it is unused there why do we have -V option with chattr to change its i_generation number?